# Fire a function on app delete in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-analytics

I need to fire a function on app delete, we are using Firebase Analytics and there are events like `app_clear_data, app_remove` so is there a way to fire a function, which looks like this:

```
const logOut = async () => {
    logOutBottomSheetModalRef.current?.close();
    try {
      await logOutQuery();
      removeAuthInfo();
      client.resetStore();
      reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: "welcome" }] });
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
  };
```

when this type of events occurs.